# Comparing the values of two generic Numbers

Tags: java, generics, numbers, comparable

I want to compare to variables, both of type `T extends Number`. Now I want to know which of the two variables is greater than the other or equal. Unfortunately I don't know the exact type yet, I only know that it will be a subtype of `java.lang.Number`. How can I do that?

**EDIT**: I tried another workaround using `TreeSet`s, which actually worked with natural ordering (of course it works, all subclasses of `Number` implement `Comparable` except for AtomicInteger and AtomicLong). Thus I'll lose duplicate values. When using `List`s, `Collection.sort()` will not accept my list due to bound mismatchs. Very unsatisfactory.

Comment: Hmm - this is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480632/why-doesnt-java-lang-number-implement-comparable

Comment: This shouldn't be tagged "generics". "Generic numbers" does not refer to Java generics in this case.

Comment: Google Collections has a TreeMultiSet which lets you sort stuff without losing duplicates.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

A working (but brittle) solution is something like this:

```
class NumberComparator implements Comparator<Number> {

    public int compare(Number a, Number b){
        return new BigDecimal(a.toString()).compareTo(new BigDecimal(b.toString()));
    }

}
```

It's still not great, though, since it counts on `toString` returning a value parsable by `BigDecimal` (which the standard Java `Number` classes do, but which the `Number` contract doesn't demand).

**Edit, seven years later:** As pointed out in the comments, there are (at least?) three special cases `toString` can produce that you need to take into regard:

- `Infinity`, which is greater than everything, except itself to which it is equal
- `-Infinity`, which is less than everything, except itself to which it is equal
- `NaN`, which is extremely hairy/impossible to compare since [all comparisons with `NaN` result in `false`, including checking equality with itself](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.1).

Comment: it's not likely but it can cause NumberFormatException if I create a subclass of Number and don't override toString in a proper way.

Comment: Hopefully the programmer will know if any descendants of Number other than the standard ones might be encountered.

Comment: Zeeks! This is a really bad solution. Though I can't off hand think of a better one, so I won't downvote yet.  :-(

Comment: @user949300 As I said, it's a _working (but brittle) solution_ which is _not great, though_ - so, I agree it's a bad solution! But the whole premise is flawed, generally one shouldn't work with arbitrary `Number`s. Best thing here probably would've been constraining the type parameter further, to `T extends Number & Comparable<T>`.

Comment: *"`toString` returning a value parsable by `BigDecimal` (which the standard Java `Number` classes do"* That is not entirely true, given that `Double` and `Float` can return 3 special values (`NaN`, `Infinity`, and `-Infinity`) that are *not* supported by `BigDecimal`.

Comment: Good catch @Andreas. You're the first one in 7 years to find it :)

Answer (score 43):

This should work for all classes that extend Number, and are Comparable to themselves. By adding the & Comparable you allow to remove all the type checks and provides runtime type checks and error throwing for free when compared to Sarmun answer.

```
class NumberComparator<T extends Number & Comparable> implements Comparator<T> {

    public int compare( T a, T b ) throws ClassCastException {
        return a.compareTo( b );
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any drawback with this answer? Otherwise it should probably be chosen as best answer.

Comment: It requires the source collection to be a specific type, so it won't work for abstract Number class.

Comment: This only works when the compareTo method of one actually accepts the other. It'll throw a ClassCastException if called with a Long and a Double.

Answer (score 18):

After having asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12561485/1374678) and studying the answers here, I came up with the following. I think it is more efficient and more robust than the solution given by gustafc:

```
public int compare(Number x, Number y) {
    if (isSpecial(x) || isSpecial(y))
        return Double.compare(x.doubleValue(), y.doubleValue());
    else
        return toBigDecimal(x).compareTo(toBigDecimal(y));
}

private static boolean isSpecial(Number x) {
    var specialDouble = x instanceof Double d
            && (Double.isNaN(d) || Double.isInfinite(d));
    var specialFloat = x instanceof Float f
            && (Float.isNaN(f) || Float.isInfinite(f));
    return specialDouble || specialFloat;
}

private static BigDecimal toBigDecimal(Number number) {
    if (number instanceof BigDecimal d)
        return d;
    if (number instanceof BigInteger i)
        return new BigDecimal(i);
    if (number instanceof Byte || number instanceof Short
            || number instanceof Integer || number instanceof Long)
        return new BigDecimal(number.longValue());
    if (number instanceof Float || number instanceof Double)
        return new BigDecimal(number.doubleValue());
    
    try {
        return new BigDecimal(number.toString());
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("The given number (\"" + number + "\" of class " + number.getClass().getName() + ") does not have a parsable string representation", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that BigDecimal.valueOf should be used instead of the constructor  ESPECIALLY for the Float/Double creation or you'll get base2 floating point errors in the conversion.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I'm not sure your point is valid though. The Javadoc of the double constructor says: "[...], note that this constructor provides an exact conversion; it does not give the same result as converting the double to a String using the `Double.toString(double)` method and then using the `BigDecimal(String)` constructor." It is true that the exact conversion often yields unexpected results (e.g. for `0.1` literals). But since we don't know anything about the numbers' origins, I think the only sensible way to handle them is to assume nothing about it.

Answer (score 17):

One solution that might work for you is to work not with `T extends Number` but with `T extends Number & Comparable`. This type means: "`T` can only be set to types that implements *both* the interfaces."

That allows you to write code that works with all comparable numbers. Statically typed and elegant.

This is the same solution that BennyBoy proposes, but it works with all kinds of methods, not only with comparator classes.

```
public static <T extends Number & Comparable<T>> void compfunc(T n1, T n2) {
    if (n1.compareTo(n2) > 0) System.out.println("n1 is bigger");
}

public void test() {
    compfunc(2, 1); // Works with Integer.
    compfunc(2.0, 1.0); // And all other types that are subtypes of both Number and Comparable.
    compfunc(2, 1.0); // Compilation error! Different types.
    compfunc(new AtomicInteger(1), new AtomicInteger(2)); // Compilation error! Not subtype of Comparable
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The most "generic" Java primitive number is double, so using simply

```
a.doubleValue() > b.doubleValue()
```

should be enough in most cases, but... there are subtle issues here when converting numbers to double. For example the following is possible with BigInteger:

```
    BigInteger a = new BigInteger("9999999999999992");
    BigInteger b = new BigInteger("9999999999999991");
    System.out.println(a.doubleValue() > b.doubleValue());
    System.out.println(a.doubleValue() == b.doubleValue());
```

results in:

```
false
true
```

Although I expect this to be very extreme case this is possible. And no - there is no generic 100% accurate way. Number interface have no method like exactValue() converting to some type able to represent number in perfect way without loosing any information.

Actually having such perfect numbers is impossible in general - for example representing number Pi is impossible using any arithmetic using finite space.

Comment: Note that this also does not work for Long either since they can also not be fully represented using Double.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(yourNumber instanceof Double) {
    boolean greaterThanOtherNumber = yourNumber.doubleValue() > otherNumber.doubleValue();
    // [...]
}
```

*Note:* The `instanceof` check isn't necessarily needed - depends on how exactly you want to compare them. You could of course simply always use `.doubleValue()`, as every Number should provide the methods listed [here](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html).

*Edit*: As stated in the comments, you will (always) have to check for BigDecimal and friends. But they provide a `.compareTo()` method:

```
if(yourNumber instanceof BigDecimal && otherNumber instanceof BigDecimal) { 
    boolean greaterThanOtherNumber = ((BigDecimal)yourNumber).compareTo((BigDecimal)otherNumber) > 0;
}
```

Comment: What about `BigDecimal` or other types out of range for doubles?

Comment: simply add a if(yourNumber instanceof BigDecimal && otherNumber instanceof BigDecimal){ boolean greaterThanOtherNumber = yourNumber.compareTo(otherNumber) > 0; }

Answer (score 2):

What about this one? Definitely not nice, but it deals with all necessary cases mentioned.

```
public class SimpleNumberComparator implements Comparator<Number>
    {
        @Override
        public int compare(Number o1, Number o2)
        {
            if(o1 instanceof Short && o2 instanceof Short)
            {
                return ((Short) o1).compareTo((Short) o2);
            }
            else if(o1 instanceof Long && o2 instanceof Long)
            {
                return ((Long) o1).compareTo((Long) o2);
            }
            else if(o1 instanceof Integer && o2 instanceof Integer)
            {
                return ((Integer) o1).compareTo((Integer) o2);
            }
            else if(o1 instanceof Float && o2 instanceof Float)
            {
                return ((Float) o1).compareTo((Float) o2);
            }
            else if(o1 instanceof Double && o2 instanceof Double)
            {
                return ((Double) o1).compareTo((Double) o2);
            }
            else if(o1 instanceof Byte && o2 instanceof Byte)
            {
                return ((Byte) o1).compareTo((Byte) o2);
            }
            else if(o1 instanceof BigInteger && o2 instanceof BigInteger)
            {
                return ((BigInteger) o1).compareTo((BigInteger) o2);
            }
            else if(o1 instanceof BigDecimal && o2 instanceof BigDecimal)
            {
                return ((BigDecimal) o1).compareTo((BigDecimal) o2);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new RuntimeException("Ooopps!");
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Like you said, not nice, shouldn't be here :)

Comment: @keni But do you have a better solution?

Comment: It doesn't deal with all the necessary cases actually, not a lot more than @BennyBoy's nor Lii's certainly and suffers the same probs as pointed out by Pr0methean. Yea, and a lot more verbose and not close to being closed to modification. No offence meant.

Answer (score 2):

This should work for all classes that extend Number, and are Comparable to themselves.

```
class NumberComparator<T extends Number> implements Comparator<T> {

    public int compare(T a, T b){
        if (a instanceof Comparable) 
            if (a.getClass().equals(b.getClass()))
                return ((Comparable<T>)a).compareTo(b);        
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `Number's doubleValue()` method to compare them; however you may find the results are not accurate enough for your needs.

Comment: I think that this is too risky

Comment: BigInteger and BigDecimal implements Number as well. This wouldn't work.

Comment: True, it could be risky and it could fail.  There are more caveats than the precision/accuracy issue I noted.  But it may suit the OP's needs if he doesn't need to handle large BigDecimals.

Answer (score 1):

In my use case, I was looking for a general `Comparator` that works with the autoboxed primitives (64 bit max precision), not arbitrary precision types like `BigInteger` and `BigDecimal`. Here's a first shot at it..

```
public class PrimitiveComparator implements Comparator<Number> {

  @Override
  public int compare(Number a, Number b) {
    if (a == b)
      return 0;
    double aD = a.doubleValue();
    double bD = b.doubleValue();
    int comp = Double.compare(aD, bD);
    if (comp == 0 && inLongBounds(aD))
      comp = Long.compare(a.longValue(), b.longValue());
    return comp;
  }
  
  private boolean inLongBounds(double value) {
    return
        Double.compare(value, Long.MAX_VALUE) <= 0 &&
        Double.compare(value, Long.MIN_VALUE) >= 0;
  }
}
```

The objective is to be able to compare mixed types (e.g. `Float`s against `Long`s). This should also work with those AtomicXxx types (or any hand rolled Number subclass that uses no more than 64 bits).

In this ordering, btw, `Double.NaN > Double.POSITVE_INFINITY > { everything else }`.

Comment: Is there an updated "first shot" or is this still the best one?

Comment: I've done some thorough testing of this one and it seems to work. I didn't use exactly this code, but equivalent code, and IntelliJ suggested replacing `a == b` with `Objects.equals()`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that you have some method like:

```
public <T extends Number> T max (T a, T b) {
   ...
   //return maximum of a and b
}
```

If you know that there are only integers, longs and doubles can be passed as parameters then you can change method signature to:

```
public <T extends Number> T max(double a, double b) {
   return (T)Math.max (a, b);
}
```

This will work for byte, short, integer, long and double.

If you presume that BigInteger's or BigDecimal's or mix of floats and doubles can be passed then you cannot create one common method to compare all these types of parameters.

Answer (score 0):

If your Number instances are ***never*** Atomic (ie AtomicInteger) then you can do something like:

```
private Integer compare(Number n1, Number n2) throws SecurityException, NoSuchMethodException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {

 Class<? extends Number> n1Class = n1.getClass();
 if (n1Class.isInstance(n2)) {
  Method compareTo = n1Class.getMethod("compareTo", n1Class);
  return (Integer) compareTo.invoke(n1, n2);
 }

 return -23;
}
```

This is since all non-Atomic `Number`s implement Comparable

**EDIT**:

This is costly due to reflection: I know

**EDIT 2**:

This of course does not take of a case in which you want to compare decimals to ints or some such...

**EDIT 3**:

This assumes that there are no custom-defined descendants of Number that do not implement Comparable (thanks @DJClayworth)

Comment: This assumes that there are no custom-defined descendants of Number.

Comment: @DJClayworth: true enough. And those are not the only constraints as I had mentioned above. But why would there be 'custom-defined descendants of Number'?

Comment: An example of a custom-defined descendant of `Number` is `org.apache.commons.math.fraction.BigFraction`, which I use in many of my programs.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem as if it is possible to compare Number objects or handle numbers with generics in other ways, however, the good news is that there are only six primitive number types, so implementing functionality that seems to be generic may be cumbersome when implementing it but can look nice to the final user.

This is how I've implemented this:

```
public class LongNumber {
    public int compareTo(byte n) {
        return Long.compare(number, ((Byte)n).longValue());
    }
    public int compareTo(short n) {
        return Long.compare(number, ((Short)n).longValue());
    }
    public int compareTo(int n) {
        return Long.compare(number, ((Integer)n).longValue());
    }
    public int compareTo(long n) {
        return Long.compare(number, n);
    }
    public int compareTo(float n) {
        return Double.compare(number.doubleValue(), ((Float)n).doubleValue());
    }
    public int compareTo(double n) {
        return Double.compare(number.doubleValue(), n);
    }

    public LongNumber(byte number) { this(((Byte)number).longValue()); }
    public LongNumber(short number) { this(((Short)number).longValue()); }
    public LongNumber(int number) { this(((Integer)number).longValue()); }
    public LongNumber(long number) { this.number = number; }

    private final Long number;
}
```

This class wraps integers (byte, short, int, long) and converts them all to Long. I've opted to use primitives in the methods to avoid having to do null checks but stored the number as a `Long` in order to make the comparisons to `float` and `double` easier.

As a user of the class, you'd do something like:

```
byte num = 64;
final LongNumber longNumber = new LongNumber(num);
System.out.println("123456L != 64: " + (longNumber.compareTo(123456L) != 0));

System.out.println("Even though (byte)123456L = " + ((Long)123456L).byteValue());

System.out.println("Is 64 > PI? " + (longNumber.compareTo(Math.PI) > 0));
```

I have another class for floating point values where I do all comparisons using `Double.compare()` instead:

```
public class DoubleNumber {
    public int compareTo(byte n) {
        return Double.compare(number, ((Byte)n).doubleValue());
    }
    public int compareTo(short n) {
        return Double.compare(number, ((Short)n).doubleValue());
    }
    public int compareTo(int n) {
        return Double.compare(number, ((Integer)n).doubleValue());
    }
    public int compareTo(long n) {
        return Double.compare(number, ((Long)n).doubleValue());
    }
    public int compareTo(float n) {
        return Double.compare(number, ((Float)n).doubleValue());
    }
    public int compareTo(double n) {
        return Double.compare(number, n);
    }

    public DoubleNumber(float number) { this(((Float)number).doubleValue()); }
    public DoubleNumber(double number) { this.number = number; }

    private final Double number;
}
```

If you want to work even more generically with numbers you could create a factory method for the classes (or actually six) that would wrap the input parameter in the correct wrapper class:

```
public static LongNumber of(int n) {
    return new LongNumber(n);
}
public static DoubleNumber of(float n) {
    return new DoubleNumber(n);
}
```

You could even create a static compare method like:

```
public static int compare(double x, int y) {
    return new DoubleNumber(x).compareTo(y);
}
```

Though, you'd need to implement 36 of them. Again, hard work when coding it, but pretty nice when using it, and if the Java-people can do `List.of(...)` like they've done (at least in Java 17), maybe 36 methods aren't such an extreme...

However, if you're willing to implement 36 static methods you might want to do something like:

```
public static int compare(double x, int y) {
    return Double.compare(x, ((Integer) y).doubleValue());
}
```

My use case is that I have a number I might want to work with more than once, so for me, wrapping it in a class where I only have to implement 6 compareTo-methods made the most sense.