# Generics for java primitive wrappers

Tags: java, generics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comparing the values of two generic Numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683202/comparing-the-values-of-two-generic-numbers)

I want to write some methods for testing `Numbers` (`Long`, `Integer`, etc) like this:

```
public static <T extends Number> boolean isBetween(T min, T max, T number) {
    return min.compareTo(number) <= 0 && max.compareTo(number) >= 0; 
}
```

But I'm getting a compile error saying:

> The method compareTo(T) is undefined for the type T

How can I fix this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480632/why-doesnt-java-lang-number-implement-comparable

Comment: Try `<T extends Number & comparable<T>>`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683202/comparing-the-values-of-two-generic-numbers?lq=1

Comment: I'd also like to see a wombat in a top hat and monocle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Number` doesn't implement `Comparable` (see [Why doesn't java.lang.Number implement Comparable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480632/why-doesnt-java-lang-number-implement-comparable) for the rationale), but you can restrict yourself to the `Number`s that do:

```
public static <T extends Number & Comparable<T>> boolean isBetween ...
```

Comment: Don't like the question? :) (btw this 30 question hat is really demeaning)

Comment: @Bohemian I hunt for the "answer" ones ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the casting. the following should work

```
return ((Comparable<T>) min).compareTo(number) <= 0 && ((Comparable<T>) max).compareTo(number) >= 0;
```