# Map: Defining a Method for Type Integer and Double but not String

Tags: java, generics, parameters, hashmap

I'm attempting to define a method `putIfGreaterThan()` for my new `Map` class (*given a key it replaces the old value with the new value only if the new value is greater than the old value*).

I understand I could accomplish this either via composition (by having a `private final Map<String, Double> map;` in new class and then passing a `Map` to constructor) or by implementing the `Map` interface in my new class and passing a `Map` to the constructor (although I'm not sure which approach is superior).

My main problem is that I need to be able to call the method `putIfGreaterThan()` on `<String, Double>` and `<String, Integer>` but not on `<String, String>` (bec it doesn't make sense to call it on `<String, String>` ). If I use generics ( `<K, V>`) the client can pass a `<String, String>` which is not allowed. On the other hand if I allow a `Double` I will not be able to pass an `Integer` or vice versa. How can I define a method to allow either Integer or Double but not String?

Note: I'm unable to define two constructors (one for Double and one for Integer) bec I get the error: Erasure of method XX is the same as another method in type XX .

Comment: You can do some stuff with `? extends Number` or something like that; I'll upvote the answerer. Gotta bug to fix right now, so can't tend to this.

Comment: Can't you use `Number` since `Double` and `Integer` extend from `Number`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the decorator pattern and limit the generics to subtypes of `Number`, which you can than compare without casting with a little trick taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2683388/1809463). It takes the string representation of the number instances and creates an instance of `BigDecimal` -  thus circumventing casting of any kind.

Below you find the relevant implementation details of the decorator, of course you'll need to override the remaining methods of the `Map` interface.

```
public class GreaterThanDecorator<K, V extends  Number> implements Map<K, V> {

    private final Map<K, V> delegate;

    public GreaterThanDecorator(Map<K, V> delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    public V putIfGreaterThan(K key, V value) {
        V old = delegate.get(key);
        if (old == null) {
            delegate.put(key, value);
            return null;
        }

        BigDecimal newValue = new BigDecimal(value.toString());
        BigDecimal oldValue = new BigDecimal(old.toString());

        if (newValue.compareTo(oldValue) >= 1)
            old = delegate.put(key, value);

        return old;
    }

}
```

Feel free to forbid the other subtypes of `Number`, i.e. by throwing an exception, as you see fit.

Comment: Well, the answers are getting better and better.

Answer (score 0):

Generics and numbers don't go together well, unfortunately. But you can do something like this:

```
public class MyMap {
    private final Map<String, Number> map = new HashMap<>();

    public void putInt(String key, int value) {
        map.put(key, value);
    }

    public void putDouble(String key, int value) {
        map.put(key, value);
    }

    public void putIfGreaterThan(String key, Number value) {
        if (value instanceof Double) {
            double doubleValue = (Double) value;
            map.compute(key, (k, v) -> {
                if (!(v instanceof Double) || v.doubleValue() > doubleValue) {
                    return v;
                } else {
                    return value
                }
            });
        } else if (value instanceof Integer) {
            int intValue = (Integer) value;
            map.compute(key, (k, v) -> {
                if (!(v instanceof Integer) || v.intValue() > intValue) {
                    return v;
                } else {
                    return value
                }
            });
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Expected Double or Integer, but got " + value);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you'd want to declare a method introducing a type parameter which `extends V & Comparable<? super V>`, but that is not valid Java.

However, you can define a static method without using the `&`.

```
public static <K, V extends Comparable<? super V>> void putIfGreater(
    Map<K,V> map, K key, V value
) {
    V old = map.get(key);
    if (old != null && value.compareTo(old) > 0) {
        map.put(key, value);
    }

    // Or: 
    //map.computeIfPresent(key, (k, old) -> value.compareTo(old) > 0 ? value : old);
}
```

If you were going down the route of different construction, then the type would need to be different for the case where `V` is `Comparable<? super V>`. If two constructors have the same erasure, it's probably time to have meaningfully named static creation methods.