# Javascript Executor Does Not Return the Correct WebElement

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I'm using JavaScript executor via Selenium to retrieve a web element by Point as follows:

```
element = (WebElement) driver.executeScript("return document.elementFromPoint(arguments[0], arguments[1])", 
                location.x, location.y); // x = 482 y = 539
```

Although I am providing the correct coordinates of the web element, Javascript seems to be returning much more than just the element I ask for.

When I attempt to print the element text using `System.out.println(element.getText());` it prints too much information.

For example, if you navigate to this page via Selenium [Map: Defining a Method for Type Integer and Double but not String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42791201/map-defining-a-method-for-type-integer-and-double-but-not-string) I am able to retrieve the x y coordinates of the element defined by the `XPath`: `.//*[@id='question']/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/div[1]/p[1]`.

When I perform the method `System.out.println(element.getText());` on the original web element (not the one returned by JS) this results in output of:

> I'm attempting to define a method putIfGreaterThan() for my new Map class (given a key it replaces the old value with the new value only if the new value is greater than the old value).

However, when I pass the coordinates via JavaScript executor the element returned begins from:

> I'm attempting to define.....

All the way through:

> You can do some stuff with ? extends Number or something like that; I'll upvote the answerer. Gotta bug to fix right now, so can't tend to this. – Bathsheba yesterday
>
> Can't you use Number since Double and Integer extend from Number? – Abubakkar yesterday
>
> add a comment

This is not the original element (it encompasses much more than the original element).

Why is it returning the entire element as appose to a section of the element? I am sure the coordinates are correct.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the coordinates returned are the top left corner. It could be that more than one element occupy that x, y coordinate and you are getting one higher in the DOM. Why do you want to return elements based on coordinates? That seems pretty fragile because any change in page layout (even to the pixel), resizing of the browser, etc. is going to get you the wrong element. Getting it via a locator is typically the best way to go.

Comment: co-ordinates will be computed based on the size of browser viewport.Different element will be returned for the same co-ordinates for different viewport size. As mentioned by @JeffC, it is not the typical way of finding a webelement.