# Why aren't number types comparable to each other?

Tags: java, comparable

In Java, the [Integer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) class implements `Comparable<Integer>`, [Double](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html) implements `Comparable<Double>`, and so on. This means you can write code like

```
new Integer(0).compareTo(new Integer(1))
```

However, you can not compare different types:

```
new Integer(0).compareTo(new Double(1)) // illegal!
```

Why don't the various [Number](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html) subclasses implement `Comparable` to each other?

Note that you *can* compare an integer and a double through `0 < 1.1` using primitives.

Comment: How can you compare an `Integer` with a `Double`?

Comment: What would a comparison between an integer and a double look like? How precise is this supposed to be? Mandatory reading around the subject: http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm

Comment: Because all are of different type of objects. They doesn't come in same hierarchy.

Comment: This question adequately answeres this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480632/why-doesnt-java-lang-number-implement-comparable?rq=1

Comment: You can simply use the operators and rely on autounboxing.

Comment: Comparable doesn't imply any type conversion.  You can write your own Comparator which does type conversion.

Comment: "Note that you can compare an integer and a double through 0 < 1.1 using primitives".  Technically, this is not true.  You are not comparing an integer and a double; the language dictates that the `int` automatically gets cast to `double`, so you are performing a type conversion and then comparing two `double`s.  This occurs only in a few specific situations.  C++ provides ways where you can get the compiler to auto-convert types to your heart's delight, which is great until you or someone else has to debug your code.