# Finding smallest value in generic ArrayList

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, max, min

I keep getting a message telling me that the operator `<` is undefined for the types `T,T`. This is happening around

```
if(index<lowest)
```

How would I go about modifying my program so that I could get the smallest and largest values of an array list using a generic method?

```
package p07;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyList<T extends Number> {
    private ArrayList<T> l;

    public MyList(ArrayList<T> l) {
        this.l=l;
    }
    public void add(T x) {
        l.add(x);
    }
    public static <T> void smallest(ArrayList<T> l) {
        T lowest=l.get(0);
        for(T index:l) {
            if(index<lowest) { 

            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you not use Math.max()?.

Comment: I don't believe we're allowed to use it

Comment: You would then probably need to use your own comparable interface implementation and use api like Collections.min/Collections.max

Comment: Why are you not returning anything from `smallest`?  Why is it static?  Why do you need to pass in the `ArrayList` that you're trying to find the smallest element of?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The compiler is right: the operator `<` is only applicable to primitive numeric type. Quoting [section 15.20.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.1) of the JLS:

> The type of each of the operands of a numerical comparison operator must be a type that is convertible (§5.1.8) to a primitive numeric type, or a compile-time error occurs.

Hence, it is not defined for Objects, not even for Numbers, because they cannot be unboxed to a primitive type: [section 5.1.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8) of the JLS:

> A type is said to be convertible to a numeric type if it is a numeric type (§4.2), or it is a reference type that may be converted to a numeric type by unboxing conversion.

What you need is to use a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) or make your objects [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html). `Comparator`s are responsible for comparing two objects of the same type. Since the objects here are Numbers, and they are not `Comparable`, you need to use a custom `Comparator`, like this:

```
Comparator<Number> myComparator = new Comparator<Number>() {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Number n1, Number n2) {
        // implement logic here.
        // Return -1 if n1 < n2, 0 if n1 = n2, 1 if n1 > n2
    }
};
```

Then you can use this comparator like this:

```
public static <T extends Number> T smallest(List<T> l) {
    T lowest = l.get(0);
    for (T index : l) {
        if (myComparator.compareTo(index, lowest) < 0) { 
            index = lowest;
        }
    }
    return lowest;
}
```

(Note that I added `T extends Number` to the type of the method - that is because the method is static so it's in fact declaring another type `T` that the one the class is).

Comment: The problem is that the question I'm trying to do only wants me to constrain the program to the upper bound of Numbers

Comment: @Matt You need to implement a `Comparator`, like the one I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I just remembered that methods can implements the Comparable inteface

Comment: I actually have one more question. If I want to use a toString method to print each element of the array list, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: @Matt You can simply use `toString` on the list itself. It will print every element.

Comment: But what if I wanted to print 5 elements of the array list to a line?

Comment: You don't really need a custom comparator in this scenario.  If you can guarantee that you're only ever inserting `Number`s, then you can leverage the `Comparable` interface on the `Number` class directly.

Comment: @Makoto [`Number` does not implement `Comparable`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/480632/1743880). I'm not sure how `Comparable` could be used here.

Comment: Ah, slip of the tongue there.  `Number` doesn't implement `Comparable`, but most every child class of it *does*.  I'll finish writing it up here in a second.

Comment: @Makoto Well not if I do `class Fraction extends Number`. How can then a `Fraction` be compared using `Comparable`?

Comment: You'd want to implement `Comparable` on `Fraction`, then.  It doesn't make sense to have a list of `Number`s which can't be rationally ordered; how on Earth would you be able to pick out which one is larger than the other?!

Comment: @Makoto In this question, we only have `T extends Number` so I don't see how can assume that `T` is also `Comparable`. Like I said in my answer, you need to implement your business logic inside a `Comparator` (for example comparing `doubleValue`). It needs to work regardless of the `Number` implementation. The question of _when_ is a `Number` a bigger than a `Number` b is up to the OP (he hasn't stated what it should be but I assume there is one)

Answer (score -1):

There are several things awry here, but let's start with the low-hanging syntax fruit.

The arithmetic operators *only* work for primitive values, and `T` is very much an `Object`, so you wouldn't be able to use them here.

Another nuance to your syntax is that you're `T` for that static function ***is not the same*** as the `T` which is bound to your class.

You can fix that, either by adding the bound yourself...

```
public static <T extends Number> void smallest(ArrayList<T> l)
```

...but this leads me to ask, why would you want this method to  be static at all?

You're obscuring the name of the field `l` with the parameter `l`, so while you may think that this is going to work for the instance's provided `l`, it won't since the method itself is declared `static`, and you'd still be shadowing the field's name if it weren't.

What you should do is remove `static` from that method, and remove the parameter from the function.

```
public void smallest() {}
```

But now, you've got an issue in that you don't actually *return* what the smallest value is.  You should return it instead of nothing:

```
public T smallest() {}
```

Getting the last value out of an array is straightforward if you're capable of sorting.  You just need to ensure that all of your elements are `Comparable` so that they can be sorted, and the values you care about the most - like `Integer`, `Double`, `Float`, `Long` - are.

```
public class MyList<T extends Number & Comparable<T>> {}
```

If you can sort, then getting the smallest is *straightforward*:

```
public T smallest() {
    // Don't mutate the order of the original array.
    ArrayList<T> listCopy = new ArrayList<>(l);
    Collections.sort(listCopy);
    return listCopy.get(0);
}
```

Getting the highest via this approach I leave as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: This is wrong. We can't assume that the `Number` the OP has are `Comparable`. Maybe he wants to compare `class Fraction extends Number` and he can't change `Fraction`.

Comment: Fundamentally it doesn't make sense to have a `Number` which isn't `Comparable`, but we'll have to see what the requirements actually are.  There's still a lot of ambiguity and confusion as to why the function was static to begin with, as well as what `Number` they're actually implementing.  I strongly doubt they're using any custom `Number` classes - this seems like a straightforward assignment - so unless the OP actually does say they're using that, then I wouldn't be so quick to say that this is "wrong".

Comment: If it didn't make sense for a `Number` not to be `Comparable` then `Number` would implement `Comparable`. It seems you don't agree with how this class was designed. There is no ambiguity in the question (apart from the whole static thing which is probably a typo): `T extends Number`, that's all.