# Why is Kotlin's Number-class missing operators?

Tags: kotlin, language-design

In Kotlin, the [`Number`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-number/index.html) type sounds quite useful: A type to use whenever I need something numeric.

When actually using it, however, I quickly noticed it is pretty useless: I cannot use any operators on these numbers. As soon as I need to do something with them, I need to explicitly convert them (even for comparing).

Why did the language designers choose to not include operators in the `Number` specification?

Thinking on this, I noticed it could be tricky to implement `Number.plus(n: Number): Number`, because `n` might be of a different type than `this`.
On the other hand, [such implementations do exist](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-float/plus.html) in all `Number` subtypes I checked. And of course they are necessary if I want to type `1 + 1.2`, which calls `Int.plus(d: Double): Double`

The result for me is that I have to call `.toDouble()` every time I use a number. This makes the code hard to read (compare `a.toDouble() < b.toDouble()` with `a < b`).

Is there any technical reason why operators where omitted from `Number`?

Comment: I think the biggest problem is, that `Number` is an abstract class and therefore allows custom implementations to be passed... how would you add a `BogusNumber` to any other `Number`?

Comment: by the way... please check [`BigDecimal#plus`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/java.math.-big-decimal/plus.html) ... for me it makes sense to not have all overloaded variants there... don't want that inaccuracy of adding float/doubles, etc. there ;-)

Comment: With `BogusNumber`: You could provide a default implementation with `toDouble()`. But even if you omit `plus`, at least a `compareTo` would be _so_ useful

Comment: Have a look at `java.lang.Number` too. Kotlin's Number is not much different.

Comment: @Qw3ry the problem is, that if you would support such a `compareTo`, you could only support the types that you know about at that time... and everyone else might be fooled, because they think it is supported but it isn't really... note also that `toDouble()` might not be the best choice... think of `BigDecimal` again... you do  not want to play (compare/add/etc.) with `Double` while operating on a `BigDecimal`. You can, but you usually don't want to...

Comment: Note also... if you really find it that useful, just add your own `fun Number.compareTo` extension function ;-) but then... just be aware that it might not always work the way you expect (in the end... `Number` is not  derived from `Comparable`, but other numbers are... and extension functions lose against existing functions...)

Comment: Okay, I guess I got your point. Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480632/why-doesnt-java-lang-number-implement-comparable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the implementation of the `compareTo` method. While it sounds reasonable and easy to add it in the first place, the devil lies in the details:

How would you compare instances of arbitrary `Number` classes to each other? Kotlin could implement the compare method using `toDouble()`; however this has problems with equality/precision: How do you compare a `BigDecimal` to a `Double`? Using `toDouble()` on the `BigDecimal` might lose precision, and [two (actually different) `BigDecimal`s might be considered equal using this method](https://pl.kotl.in/5vIBy2iDS).
The mess gets even worse when you start to assume one or both types were supplied by libraries, where you cannot make assumptions on precision etc.

In Java, the [`Number` type is not `Comparable` either](https://stackoverflow.com/a/481404/2448440).
Furthermore, [some `Number` values like `NaN` might not be comparable at all](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4414323).

If you need a `Number` to be comparable, you can easily implement your own `compareTo`-method as extension function. This has some additional limitations though, as most `Number` subtypes implement `Comparable`, and the extension function will lose against that implementation.

Credit for this answer goes to [Roland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6202869), I only extended his comments (see on the question) into an answer.

Comment: You just took wrong example. Converting double to BigDecimal and comparing them would work. We just make simple assumption that 10 = 10.00.  Numbers ARE comparable, because they come from so called MATH. Number.compare should be part of language.

Comment: Actually, it does not: https://pl.kotl.in/5vIBy2iDS

Comment: Of course you can compare numbers in _MATH_. But programming is not simple math, because your numbers have different representations on storage, and might be imprecise. If you supply a `MyBestDecimal : Number` and a library you are using supplies some `OurBestDecimal : Number`, they might have arbitrary implementations of those classes, and with the methods given by `Number` you cannot compare them reliably