# Proper use of Number class in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, generics

Can anyone help me implement these methods in Kotlin?
I want to find min, max elements of array of numbers and also sort array in ascending order. Here is a code

```kotlin
class DataArray<Number>(vararg numbers: Number) {
    private val array = mutableListOf<Number>(*numbers)

    fun getMin() {
        return array.minByOrNull { it! } //doesn't work
    }

    fun getMax() = array.max() //doesn't work
    fun sort() = array.sort()  //doesn't work


    private fun <E> MutableList<E>.max(): Any { //was created to use in function above, but resulted in stack overflow
        return this.max()
    }

    private fun <E> MutableList<E>.sort(): Any { //was created to use in function above, but resulted in stack overflow
        return this.sort()
    }

    override fun toString(): String {
        var str = ""
        for(i in array)
            str += "$i "
        return str
    }
}

fun main() {

    val arr = DataArray(2, 5, 2, 6, 9, -3, 56, 16, 72, 8)
    println(arr.getMax())
    println(arr.getMin())
    println(arr.sort())
    print(arr)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the word `Number` here declares a generic parameter called `Number`. It does not refer to `kotlin.Number`. You might have intended it to declare a generic parameter with a bound of `Number` instead, in which case you should have written:

```
class DataArray<T: Number>(vararg numbers: T) {
    ...
}
```

But even if you did, it still wouldn't work as [`Number`s are not comparable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57392668/why-is-kotlins-number-class-missing-operators).

You would have to further constrain `T` to `Comparable<T>`:

```
 class DataArray<T: Number>(vararg numbers: T) where T: Comparable<T> {
```

Then you can do:

```
fun getMin() = array.minOrNull()
fun getMax() = array.maxOrNull()
fun sort() = array.sort()
```

Extension functions on `MutableList` are unnecessary.

(Note that technically, the `T: Number` constraint is also unnecessary if you just want to use `minOrNull`, `maxOrNull`, and `sort`. I'm assuming you are planning on using one of the methods in `kotlin.Number`. Otherwise you can delete that constraint.)

You seem to be trying to implement your own `MutableList` by delegation. Keep in mind that you can easily do this using `by`:

```
class DataArray<T: Number>(
        vararg numbers: T
) : MutableList<T> by mutableListOf(*numbers) {
    override fun toString(): String {
        var str = ""
        for(i in this) // rather than "array", use "this"
            str += "$i "
        return str
    }
}
```